# I don't remember my Live ID

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

I have an old xbox360 and my account is there. I want to download my account on the new black Xbox360. The thing is, I don't remember the email associated with that gamertag.

How can I get it?

Answer (score 12):

### Gamertag is still accessible on an Xbox 360

Go to your **Xbox Guide** (center button) => **Settings** => **Account Management** => **Windows Live ID**. The Windows Live ID associated with the signed-in Gamertag will show.

[image: Account Management]<sup>[1](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/billing-and-subscriptions/account-management/manage-live-id#12e33633bdb7464bb4a6ae4146556885)</sup>

### Gamertag is not on any Xbox 360

**Contact Xbox support directly via [support.xbox.com/contact](http://support.xbox.com/contact).** The site will give you an option to chat live or speak to a rep depending on the time of day. They are used to these requests. They'll ask you some questions to verify your ownership/identity before handing over your Windows Live ID.

Guessing your account details is most likely a waste of your time.

Comment: I guess you are right. Seems like the only way. Thank you

Comment: The live chat service is actually surprisingly good.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the site and try emails which you think only the one which exists in the data base will be accepted if you remember your email addresses!

Comment: I did that, still couldnt get it. Because I am sure that one of the emails should be the right one, but when I log in (and it accepts it) it opens a new gamertag with a default name they gave me, not my actual gamertag